# Variable amount for Stripe

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I want to use Stripe and charge my client with a variable amount, depends on a size boat, and the price of the foot increase like this :

20-29 feet > Price of the foot : 12 $ 
30-39 feet > Price of the foot : 16 $

and so on.

If i resume with the help i have so far.

I need to made a form in my page with variable values :

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
<select name="boat_value" id="boat_value" required>
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Choose boat size</option>
    <option value="1200">20 - 29 ft</option>
    <option value="1600">30 - 39 ft</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I need to create a charge.php

```
<?php // Get boat value. Apply some simple security here (apply further if putting in DB later)
isset ($_POST['boat_value']) ? $boat_value = $_POST['boat_value'] : '';


 // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe::setApiKey("mykeys");

// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];


// Charge the user's card with variable amount:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => $boat_value,
"currency" => "eur",
"description" => "Example charge",
"source" => $token,
));
```

I think i have to implement something else on the page for everything work out. But i'm stuck here.

So a few questions :

Where i put charge.php on my wordpress host ? In the theme folder directly ? Did i have to initialize it in function.php ?

Do i have to use this code too in my page ?

```
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="yourkeyhere"
data-amount="999"
data-name="widget"
data-description="Widget"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout /marketplace.png"
data-locale="auto"
data-zip-code="true"
data-currency="eur">
</script>
</form>
```

If someone have any clue to calculate my custom amount and put it in the amount form, it would be awesome.

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I can't see the rest of your code but hopefully the snippet you posted is in 'charge.php' or similar and not on the same page as the form. I would have the initial form POST to charge.php.

Assuming you are using a dropdown to choose boat size, something like this should work:

index.php:

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
    <select name="boat_value" id="boat_value" required>
        <option selected="selected" disabled>Choose boat size</option>
        <option value="1200">20 - 29 ft</option>
        <option value="1600">30 - 39 ft</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

charge.php:

```
<?php // Get boat value. Apply some simple security here (apply further if putting in DB later)
isset ($_POST['boat_value']) ? $boat_value = $_POST['boat_value'] : '';

// Charge the user's card with variable amount:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $boat_value,
    "currency" => "eur",
    "description" => "Example charge",
    "source" => $token,
));
```

Also, the [Stripe IRC](http://irc.lc/freenode/stripe) can be very helpful.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Actually, i was using a plugin to work with stripe. So i'm a little bit confused on the way to work that out. 

1°) I create my account on Stripe
2°) I need to implement charge.php on my wordpress. Do i have to copy charge.php to the roots of my theme files and integrate it with function.php ? 
3°) I use your code to checkout. 

Am i right ?

Comment: Ah right sorry, I didn't know you were using a plugin for this. I would consult the docs of that specific plugin, or ask around on the Stripe IRC for some help.

Comment: I was using the plugin, but the variable amount was not integrated in it. So i need to do everything from scratch. I update my question, i think i'm not so far from the answer, just missing something... :)

Comment: No worries. The charge.php file will go in your theme folder. It should be posted to by your 'buy' form. The charge.php code I gave you will create the charge with the variable amount.

You can put the 'index.php' code in whatever file you want your form to be in, as long as it can post to 'charge.php'. This should be all you need to create a simple charge, assuming your Stripe config has been setup properly (secret keys etc)

Comment: For resume, i have set my charge.php with the code you gave me at the root of my wordpress theme. 
I put the form code in my paiement page. 
But no stripe button appear...
When i use the normal payment form found on the stripe documentation, Stripe works fine but the amount is hard coded.. 
So i guess my stripe installation is fine... 
Do i have ton install checkout library on my wordpress or it's not necessary ? 

Thank again for the help

Comment: The 'simple checkout' offered by Stripe won't allow you to have variable prices, so you will need to do a custom checkout. Yes, you will also need to include the Stripe library. See here for instructions:

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: Ok thanks. I need to figure out how to add a library in wordpress with composer. Come back after that. :)

Comment: I need to ask to the stackoverflow community how to add a third part library to Wordpress. I read so many thing on internet that i'm lost. Come back here when i'll have the answer :) I really want to learn how to use Stripe with custom paiement !

Comment: Sorry for not getting back, I'll help later or tomorrow when I'm at a laptop again.

Comment: Okay so, the PHP Stripe library can be downloaded here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases. Full install instructions are here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php. You should use Composer if you have it installed, if not just follow the alternative instructions.

This along with the code I gave you will create a simple charge for the customer, and you can just work through the docs from there: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php :)

Comment: Sorry for late answer, i'm busy this week. Try this next week and come back to you. Thx.